# How to parse multiple different API URLs in Android without creating same classes which are extended by AsyncTasks Classes?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, flickr, android-viewholder

Hello Dear Developers,

I am working on a project which uses `Flickr API`, I parsed the data and took the necessary values from `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`, however  the URL does not provide all the necessary information about the user (the user who shared the photo on Flickr )  for this reason I decided to use [flickr.people.getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.people.getInfo) but in this situation, how can I handle response `JSON`, I mean if I parse this URL, I have to change `RecyclerView` `Adapter`, `ViewHolder`, but it is not sufficient way of handling multiple different API calls.

I hope, the explanation is clear, if it is not pleasing make comment then I will provide answers to your specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you should make two calls, then merge responses together and show result into UI.

You can handle this with callbacks or `RxJava` `observables`. 
The main idea is to create a single class - model that will contain all data you need to present on your UI. Then make the first network call and parse the response into this object. Pass this object to the next network call and update it with the corresponding user data. And only after these two calls are done and you collected all needed data you can insert the model into RecyclerView.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not know what the RxJava observables but I will search on it. However, even I make two calls and merge them, the viewholder methods of the recyclerview should change according to the data which is binding for the adapter. I confused at this point because I do not want to make another viewholder and adapter. But for both UI of the app is using recyclerview, so how can i distinguish them without making their own recyclerview and viewholder. Thanks for answering.

Comment: You can find some details of chaining networking calls with RxJava here: https://blog.doordash.com/synchronizing-network-calls-with-rxjava-d30f7db66fb9

As for Recycler view - you don't need to make another viewholder. 
The idea is to get ALL data from Flickr API first and only after that present it to RecyclerView. It should be done once.

Comment: Alright, I will try to make the calls using RxJava to get ALL data from Flickr API. Thank you for your interesting and answers.